# Stream input to external process in Scala

Tags: scala, streaming

I have an Iterable[String] and I want to stream that to an external Process and return an Iterable[String] for the output.

I feel like this should work as it compiles

```
import scala.sys.process._

object PipeUtils {
  implicit class IteratorStream(s: TraversableOnce[String]) {
    def pipe(cmd: String) = s.toStream.#>(cmd).lines
    def run(cmd: String) = s.toStream.#>(cmd).!
  }
}
```

However, Scala tries to execute the contents of s instead of pass them in to standard in.  Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I think that my original problem was that the s.toStream was being implicity converted to a ProcessBuilder and then executed.  This is incorrect as it's the input to the process.

I have come up with the following solution.  This feels very hacky and wrong but it seems to work for now.  I'm not writing this as an answer because I feel like the answer should be one line and not this gigantic thing.

```
object PipeUtils {

  /**
   * This class feels wrong.  I think that for the pipe command it actually loads all of the output
   * into memory.  This could blow up the machine if used wrong, however, I cannot figure out how to get it to
   * work properly.  Hopefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095469/stream-input-to-external-process-in-scala
   * will get some good responses.
   * @param s
   */
  implicit class IteratorStream(s: TraversableOnce[String]) {

    val in = (in: OutputStream) => {
      s.foreach(x => in.write((x + "\n").getBytes))
      in.close
    }

    def pipe(cmd: String) = {
      val output = ListBuffer[String]()
      val io = new ProcessIO(in,
      out => {Source.fromInputStream(out).getLines.foreach(output += _)},
      err => {Source.fromInputStream(err).getLines.foreach(println)})

      cmd.run(io).exitValue
      output.toIterable
    }

    def run(cmd: String) = {
      cmd.run(BasicIO.standard(in)).exitValue
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT

The motivation for this comes from using Spark's .pipe function on an RDD.  I want this exact same functionality on my local code.

Comment: You're right about the implicit conversion from `s.toStream` to a ProcessBuilder. Anyways, wouldn't `def pipe(cmd: String): Stream[String] = (cmd +: s.toSeq).lineStream` also work or am I missing something?

Comment: How would this work for an infinite stream as an input?  Or in the case of the real world a very large stream that is too big to fit in Seq?

Comment: Ok, wasn't clear to me, that your input potentially can be very big.

Comment: Also the solution you provided causes the native program to fail.  I think that what you said puts the input as parameters.  The input is not parameters, it's being read from stdin.  Think 'cat file.txt | cmd'

Comment: Yes, you're right, so I obviously missed something. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution demonstrating how to write the process code so that it streams both the input and output.  The key is to produce a `java.io.PipedInputStream` that is passed to the input of the process.  This stream is filled from the iterator asynchronously via a `java.io.PipedOutputStream`.  Obviously, feel free to change the input type of the implicit class to an `Iterable`.

Here's an iterator used to show this works.

```
/**
 * An iterator with pauses used to illustrate data streaming to the process to be run.
 */
class PausingIterator[A](zero: A, until: A, pauseMs: Int)(subsequent: A => A) 
extends Iterator[A] {
  private[this] var current = zero
  def hasNext = current != until
  def next(): A = {
    if (!hasNext) throw new NoSuchElementException
    val r = current
    current = subsequent(current)
    Thread.sleep(pauseMs)
    r
  }
}
```

Here's the actual code you want

```
import java.io.PipedOutputStream
import java.io.PipedInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.PrintWriter

// For process stuff
import scala.sys.process._
import scala.language.postfixOps

// For asynchronous stream writing.
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

/**
 * A streaming version of the original class.  This does not block to wait for the entire 
 * input or output to be constructed.  This allows the process to get data ASAP and allows 
 * the process to return information back to the scala environment ASAP.  
 *
 * NOTE: Don't forget about error handling in the final production code.
 */
implicit class X(it: Iterator[String]) {
  def pipe(cmd: String) = cmd #< iter2is(it) lineStream

  /**
   * Convert an iterator to an InputStream for use in the pipe function.
   * @param it an iterator to convert
   */
  private[this] def iter2is[A](it: Iterator[A]): InputStream = {
    // What is written to the output stream will appear in the input stream.
    val pos = new PipedOutputStream
    val pis = new PipedInputStream(pos)
    val w = new PrintWriter(pos, true)

    // Scala 2.11 (scala 2.10, use 'future').  Executes asynchrously.  
    // Fill the stream, then close.
    Future {
      it foreach w.println
      w.close
    }

    // Return possibly before pis is fully written to.
    pis
  }
}
```

The final call will show display 0 through 9 and will pause for 3 seconds in between the displaying of each number (second pause on the scala side, 1 second pause on the shell script side).

```
// echo-sleep.sh is the same script as in my previous post
new PausingIterator(0, 10, 2000)(_ + 1)
  .map(_.toString)
  .pipe("echo-sleep.sh")
  .foreach(println)
```

Output

```
0          [ pause 3 secs ]
1          [ pause 3 secs ]
...
8          [ pause 3 secs ]
9          [ pause 3 secs ]
```

Comment: Following this example, we succeed in making the streaming IO very efficient. The key is to read from another thread, as lineStream is otherwise a blocking call

Answer (score 4):

Assuming scala 2.11+, you should use `lineStream` as suggested by @edi.  The reason is that you get a streaming response as it becomes available instead of a batched response.  Let's say I have a shell script `echo-sleep.sh`:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
# echo-sleep.sh
while read line; do echo $line; sleep 1; done
```

and we want to call it from scala using code like the following:

```
import scala.sys.process._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

implicit class X(in: TraversableOnce[String]) {
  // Don't do the BAOS construction in real code.  Just for illustration.
  def pipe(cmd: String) = 
    cmd #< new ByteArrayInputStream(in.mkString("\n").getBytes) lineStream
}
```

Then if we do a final call like:

```
1 to 10 map (_.toString) pipe "echo-sleep.sh" foreach println
```

a number in the sequence appears on STDOUT every 1 second.  If you buffer, and convert to an `Iterable` as in your example, you will lose this responsiveness.

Comment: How would this work when the input is very large?  Is this a streaming input?

Comment: Also, I know you suggested not to use BOAS for real, so how would you do this for real?